# Extracting command data from a REST API

Tags: c#

I have a method in C# which communicates with REST API.It has a several small task like splitting of a string ,checking a commandText is valid or not,POST and GET JSON payload to/from REST API.

```
  public  string PostToAPI([FromBody]string value)
        {
            string input = value;
            //splitting of string into substrings
               var str = input.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 2);
                var payload = new testModel
               {
                   Command = str[0],
                   CommandText = str[1]
               };
            //list of commands
              List<string> cmdText = new List<string>(){"/calc", "/test" };
            //check CommandText is valid or not
              if(cmdText.Contains(payload.CommandText))
              {
               //return valid
              }

            // Serialize our concrete class into a JSON String
            var stringPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
             try
             {
                 // Wrap our JSON inside a StringContent which then can be used by the HttpClient class
                 var httpContent = new StringContent(stringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                  using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())

                 {
                     HttpResponseMessage message = httpClient.PostAsync("https://testapi.com", httpContent).Result;
                     if (message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                     {
                         string result = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                         return result;
                     }
                     else
                     return message.StatusCode+"kindly contact to administrator";

                 }
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 return ex.InnerException.ToString();
             }

            }
```

splitting of a string splits the string into two substrings.

checking a commandtext, checks commandtext is valid or not.

they all are in one method.From architecture/design point of view is this right or should i split the task into different module or in different classes to add more flexibility, readability,As there may be a situation where i just need to add commands string and don't want to touch the other task.

How to organize such c# tasks into different modules/class to make them more flexible, readable?
Thanks!

Comment: In the title you should describe what your code does and not what you want to do with it.

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, **try to write a title that summarizes what your code does**, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 2):

What's the point of `string input = value;`? Why not work with `value` directly?

---

Comments should tell me why,  not what. If you suspect I cannot detect `//splitting of string into substrings` from your code, then your code is bad.

---

`testModel` is a class and thus should be PascalCase;.

---

`cmdText` is a collection of commands? That variable name doesn't suggest so at all. No wonder you need to preface it with `//list of commands`. If it is a list of commands, call it `commands`. Or considering the context, `validCommands`.

---

What's the point of this:

```
if(cmdText.Contains(payload.CommandText))
{
    //return valid
}
```

This doesn't do anything.

---

You start out using `var`, yet later on you get more explicit: `HttpResponseMessage message`, `string result`. Be consistent.

Same for your `if`...`else`:

```
if (message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string result = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    return message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
else
return message.StatusCode+"kindly contact to administrator";
```

The bad indentation hide that `return message.StatusCode+"kindly contact to administrator";` is actually your `else`. Always use brackets!

---

What's the point of `string result = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`? Why not simply `return message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`?

---

Quite frankly this code looks very unfinished. Your style is inconsistent, indentation is all over the place, there are superfluous blank lines (after `using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())` for instance), the comments are superfluous, there's code in there that doesn't do anything,...

This also looks like a method in a Controller, and that's worrying. Because even if it's a mere 50 lines, if you have several methods like this pretty soon your controller class will be very bloated. Moreover this one method does three things:

- convert the incoming data into a `payload`
- checking the `payload` against a list of values
- posting the `payload` to another API

Each of these should be their own method, and thus the body of this controller should be its own class, split into multiple methods. Look for instance at [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR) to ["un-bloat" your controllers](http://codeopinion.com/thin-controllers-cqrs-mediatr/).